# What are the main web server types, and the documentation on the files and programs to configure them?

Tags: webserver

I already know enough about the Apache HTTP Server, but what are the other most popular web server types? And where I can get the programs and documentation on how to set them up?

Answer (score 1):

that depends on which OS you are using.

in Linux the apache http in all his forms ( tomcat/catalina/httpd ) is the most common , afterwards the nginx is also quite common.

I am less familiar with windows but I think IIS is the most common in windows.